# How to get string text from AutoCompleteTextView in android?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

```
public class FareActivity extends Activity {


int fareid;
String Source;
String Dest;
AutoCompleteTextView source;
AutoCompleteTextView dest;


static final String[] SOURCE = new String[] {
      "Delhi", "Mumbai", "Agra", "Jaipur};


static final String[] DEST = new String[] {
      "Delhi", "Mumbai", "Agra", "Jaipur};




/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fare);




    dest = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.acdest);
    ArrayAdapter<String> dadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, DEST);
    dest.setAdapter(dadapter);



source = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.acsource);
ArrayAdapter<String> sadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, SOURCE);
    dest.setAdapter(sadapter);




 // Fare id calculation

     if(Source=="Delhi" && Dest=="Jaipur")
     {
         fareid=1;
     }
     else  if(Source=="Delhi" && Dest=="Agra")
     {
         fareid=2;
     }
     else  if(Source=="Delhi" && Dest=="Mumbai")
     {
         fareid=3;
     }
```

}

I just want to store autocompletetextview 'source' and autocompletetextview 'dest' values to String variable 'Source' and String Variable 'Dest'. I will use both string variables for further processing in my project, so please help me out.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide some information on what you have tried so far to get the string text from AutoCompleteTextView. This is a very good thing to do as answerers will be more willing to answer your question when you can show them what you have tried and where you have failed.

Comment: I just updated this question.

Comment: Sunil, I have requested you to update the question in the hope that someone who is an expert would be able to answer your question. Unfortunately enough, I would not be much of help in relation to android questions. Please wait for some more time for any responses. If you are in a hurry, I would suggest deleting this question, (which you can do only if no answers have been posted on the question yet) and repost your question as it is in its current form. Good luck.

Comment: I see there is an answer now. Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first you need to define the `threshold value`. Its the number of characters you want to start populating the list of characters with.

`acTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextbox);
acTextView.setThreshold(3);`

then,

`add a textwatcher and implement addTextChangedListener AutoCompleteTextView`.

Below is an example:

```
TextWatcher fieldValidatorTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (filterLongEnough()) {

                String str=acTextView.getText().toString().trim();
                populateList(str);//Function in which i am using the strings from DB, u dnt need it but just in case
            }
        }

        private boolean filterLongEnough() {
            return acTextView.getText().toString().trim().length() > 2;
        }
    };
    acTextView.addTextChangedListener(fieldValidatorTextWatcher);
```